# git squash and preserve last commit's timestamp

Tags: git

Consider I have commits

```
... -- A -- B -- C
```

If I use `git rebase -i` to squash all three commits into one, we could

```
pick A
squash B
squash C
```

I see the resulted commit `A` has its original timestamp. How could make it inherit the timestamp of commit `C` (the last one)?

What I can think of is `git commit --amend --date=<new_time>`, but this way needs to remember the timestamp of commit `C` before squash or from reflog.

I find the timestamp of the latest commit is more reasonable, because it shows when I actually finished the work that are in the commits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's not a trivial way to do this, but there are a few options.  Here's one:

```
git commit --amend --date="$(git show -s --pretty=tformat:%ai <sha1-of-C>)"
```

And another:

```
git commit --amend -c <sha1-of-C>
```

The latter will clobber your existing commit message, so you'll have to rewrite it.

Comment: @CrendKing:  In this case it doesn't matter whether it's `format` or `tformat` because the `tformat` newline is stripped by the shell's command substitution rules.  However, 99% of the time I want the final newline (or whatever the terminator is) because I'm usually parsing the custom log output with a script.  In order to ensure that I habitually type `tformat` when it matters, I use `tformat` even when it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

`git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: This doesn't use the timestamp from C, it uses the current time as the timestamp.

Comment: This does not do exactly what the OP requested, but (at least to my mind) closer matches what is usually wanted.