# Which date formats are IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, rfc, rfc2822

I need to parse dates in JavaScript. The format is

> [2 digits day]/[2 digits month]/[4 digits year] [2 digits hour (24 mode)]:[2 digits minute]

For example, `16/02/2013 21:00`

But if I do `new Date('16/02/2013 21:00').toString()`, it gives `'Wed Apr 02 2014 21:00:00 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)'`.

I guess that's because my dates don't follow IETF RFC 2822 Date and Time Specification. Then, I should convert my string, and I want to convert it to the most similar compliant format (because it should be easier to convert). But https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14 is hard to understand, so I don't know which is the most similar format.

Is there a list with examples of the allowed formats?

Comment: RFC2822 allows a single digit day value. Something to beware of.

Comment: Note that as of ECMAScript 2017, there are 2 formats supported by ECMA-262 for parsing, anything else is implementation dependent. The formats are those specified for *Date.prototype.toString*, *toISOString* (a slight modification of ISO 8601 extended). Implementations must also support whatever they produce for *toLocaleString*, but the format itself is not specified. Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760) has several examples of valid date formats:

```
document.writeln((new Date("2010")).toUTCString()); 

document.writeln((new Date("2010-06")).toUTCString());

document.writeln((new Date("2010-06-09")).toUTCString());

 // Specifies Z, which indicates UTC time.
document.writeln((new Date("2010-06-09T15:20:00Z")).toUTCString());

 // Specifies -07:00 offset, which is equivalent to Pacific Daylight time.
document.writeln((new Date("2010-06-09T15:20:00-07:00")).toGMTString());

// Specifies a non-ISO Long date.
document.writeln((new Date("June 9, 2010")).toUTCString());

// Specifies a non-ISO Long date.
document.writeln((new Date("2010 June 9")).toUTCString());

// Specifies a non-ISO Short date and time.
document.writeln((new Date("6/9/2010 3:20 pm")).toUTCString());

// Output:
// Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 UTC
// Tue, 1 Jun 2010 00:00:00 UTC
// Wed, 9 Jun 2010 00:00:00 UTC
// Wed, 9 Jun 2010 15:20:00 UTC
// Wed, 9 Jun 2010 22:20:00 UTC
// Wed, 9 Jun 2010 07:00:00 UTC
// Wed, 9 Jun 2010 07:00:00 UTC
// Wed, 9 Jun 2010 22:20:00 UTC
```

### Gotchas

There's a matrix of [cross-browser inconsistencies](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) as well.

**References**

- [Same Markup: Writing Cross-Browser Code – IEBlog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/04/14/same-markup-writing-cross-browser-code/)
- [Loading Javascript files in parallel – Kristoffer's tidbits](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kristoffer/2006/12/22/loading-javascript-files-in-parallel/)

Answer (score 3):

This question seems to be asking "*What formats are required to be parsed by ECMAScript implementations*".

Prior to ECMAScript Ed 5 (2011), parsing was entirely implementation dependent. The formats that ECMAScript implementations are required to parse can be summarised as:

1. A single (though slightly modified) version of ISO 8601 extended format called the "[date time string format](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)" introduced in ECMAScript ed 5 (2011). It differs from ISO 8601 in that date-only forms are treated as UTC, not local and the timezone offset must have a colon between the hours and minutes.
2. The format produced by an implementation's own [*toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) method, which was standardised in ECMAScript 2018
3. The format produced by an implementation's own [*toUTCString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) method, also standardised in ECMAScript 2018

Parsing of any other format remains implementation dependent and there are differences, so the general rule is "don't use the built-in parser".