# iOS vs Android: different dates displayed for the same program

Tags: javascript, debugging, mobile, cross-browser, date-conversion

I have a javascript code:

```
newDate: function(days) {
    var newDate = new Date( parseInt(startDate) + 1*1000*3600);

    var date = newDate .getDate();
    return date ;
},
```

Seems like this is the part of the program that produces different results on Android and iOS. All the rest data is the same.
How can it produce different results on Android vs iOS?

Comment: You should provide an example with the results your receiving from both and the "startdate" parameter value as well as the "days" value even though you don't seem to be using that in your function code.

Comment: What is the input, how is it different. Give the details!

Comment: What dates in particular? This might be a format issue.

Answer (score 3):

The `Date` constructor is only consistent cross-browser for the following Date formats:

```
"2010"

"2010-06"

"2010-06-09"

"2010-06-09T15:20:00Z"

"2010-06-09T15:20:00-07:00"

"2010/06/09"

"2009/6/9"

"2010/6/9 12:34"

"2010/6/9 12:34:56"

"June 9, 2010"

"2010 June 9"
```

**References**

- [Cross-browser JavaScript Date parsing behavior](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)
- [JavaScript Date Parsing Changes in ES6](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/06/17/javascript-date-parsing-changes-in-es6/)
- [How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/1113772)
- [Which date formats are IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914739/1113772)
- [Time Programming](http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/)
- [Date Timestamp Guidelines (pdf)](https://www.edf.org/sites/default/files/asw-date-timestamp-guidelines.pdf)
- [Sources for time zone and daylight saving time data](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html)