# Git when squashing branches via command line, how can I update the date of the message

Tags: git

If squashing multiple branches how can I get the message date to get updated?

e.g.
I just spent the last hour trying to find a copy of the code in order to verify what I have is up to date because the date on the last message is from 2 weeks ago when I know yesterday I had squashed a small fix into the branch.

Is it possible to get the date updated when squashing?

Based on an old post from 2012 it looks like this is a close solution:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

but I don't want to have to be prompted and I don't want to have to specify manually the date.

```
git commit --amend --date="Wed Apr 15 13:00 2037 -0700"
```

How can I make it automatically set the date to now as I don't want to have to enter the date manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I squash commits in git with a commit date that is not in the past?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262465/how-do-i-squash-commits-in-git-with-a-commit-date-that-is-not-in-the-past)

Comment: @lucidbrot Thank you very much for the link. I think that is what I'll be needing to do for now on.

Comment: Nice! Happy to help ^.^ I also learnt something new today

Comment: @lucidbrot the linked solution does work but I still have to do a couple additional steps. Might you know how I can automatically get the date updated without having to go into the prompting, or manually setting a date?

Comment: You can use the [no-edit flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365442/2550406) as in `git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author`. But after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61237201/2550406) it sounds like that can lead to confusions and it's better to use `git commit --amend --date="now" --no-edit`